# A redundant data service

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I've got a service that loads data from a databasr and it performs almost the same operations in all methods.

```
   private async Task GetProvenances()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await commonRepository.GetProvenances();
            if (result != null)
            {
                provenanceContainerService.Provenances = result;
                LogTo.Information(InitCacheMessages.STR_GET_PROVENANCES, result.Count);
            }
            else
            {
                LogTo.Warning(InitCacheMessages.STR_GET_PROVENANCES_FAILED);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptionService.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }

    private async Task GetPkInstrumentMarkets()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await commonRepository.GetPkInstrumentMarkets();
            if (result != null)
            {
                pkInstrumentMarketContainerService.PkInstrumentMarkets = result;
                LogTo.Information(InitCacheMessages.STR_GET_PK_INSTRUMENT_MARKETS, result.Count);
            }
            else
            {
                LogTo.Warning(InitCacheMessages.STR_GET_PK_INSTRUMENT_MARKETS_FAILED);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptionService.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }

    private async Task GetPkMotivations()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await commonRepository.GetPkMotivations();
            if (result != null)
            {
                pkMotivationsContainerService.PkMotivations = result;
                LogTo.Information(InitCacheMessages.STR_GET_PK_MOTIVATIONS, result.Count);
            }
            else
            {
                LogTo.Warning(InitCacheMessages.STR_GET_PK_MOTIVATIONS_FAILED);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptionService.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }
```

How can I refactor this so I don't have to repeat the same code for about 30 methods?

## UPDATE 1

Hello,
I've done this way this night

```
  protected async Task PerformInitInternal(string okMessage, string koMessage, Func<Task<IList<T>>> function)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await function();
            if (result != null)
            {
                Items = result;
                LogTo.Information(okMessage, result.Count);
            }
            else
            {
                LogTo.Warning(koMessage);
            }

            isInitialized = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionService.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }
```

And I call it this way

```
  public override Task Init()
    {
        return PerformInitInternal(InitCacheMessages.STR_GET_COUNTERPARTS,
            InitCacheMessages.STR_GET_COUNTERPARTS_FAILED, () => CommonRepository.GetCrossSplitAsync());
    }
```

Can this be ok?

Comment: Use a delegate.

Comment: can you please provide me a sample? since it's async

Comment: @advapi - delegates can be async too. E.g. async lamdba: `async (commonRepository) =>     await commonRepository.GetProvenances())`

Comment: I'm not able to solve this problem...feel really dumb, can you please post me how the method should like?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add additional context code, we need to know what a `commonRepository` is, for example. Mind including the fields and constructor of that class?

Comment: As @Mat'sMug says above we need more context. Your code could be made "better" by using generics and interfaces to set a common set of data in this fashion. For example `commonRepository.Get<PkInstrumentMarket>()`, and having an interface with a common `Results` collection for storage. The main complication would be the differing strings, could you not standardise your messages at point of failure / information, maybe passing in a type to differentiate?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Please make it seamless, and ensure the code snippets in the question are all about the same version of the code - if the top part is no longer relevant, remove it from the post. This will help reviewers, and future readers that will try to relate answers to parts of the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to review just a small part of your code like this (for example, the way you're using `Items` and `isInitialized` looks like code smell to me, but it's hard to tell like this), so I'll focus on what I can actually see.

---

```
protected async Task PerformInitInternal(string okMessage, string koMessage, Func<Task<IList<T>>> function)
```

- It's an asynchronous method, so its name should end with `Async`. Also, `PerformInit` is pretty vague, maybe a more concrete name could be better, for example, `LoadData`?
- While the symmetry between OK and KO is fun, I don't think `koMessage` is a good name. `successMessage` and `errorMessage` would be better.
- Speaking of which, do you actually need both messages? Or any messages at all? I would consider a completely generic message, assuming the rest of the message can be inferred from other parts of the log, like the type name.
- `function` is too vague.